# Draw a line across different layout-containers

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I'm building a C# WPF application and in one of my XAML Views I need to connect two controls that reside in different containers using a line.

Here is my simplified layout pseudo-code:

```
<DockPanel>
   <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      <Button Name="Button1" />
   </Grid>
   <UniformGrid Columns="3" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
      <StackPanel>
         <Button Name="ButtonA" />
      </StackPanel>
      <StackPanel>
         <Button Name="ButtonB" />
      </StackPanel>
      <StackPanel>
         <Button Name="ButtonC" />
      </StackPanel>
   </UniformGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

My requirement is to connect Button1 to ButtonA, B or C through a Line but I can't figure out how. From what I've researched normally people use Canvas and connect the controls hosted in that Canvas and use the attached properties Canvas.SetTop and Canvas.SetLeft to position the controls inside the container. I tried wrapping my DockPanel with a Canvas but that didn't work out.

My question is: Is it possible to draw lines that connect controls across different types of layouts? (in my case DockPanel-Grid-UniformGrid) or what is an alternative or more standard way of achieving this. I also tried getting my control positions relative to the DockPanel but didn't work either...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're on the right track. Put a background with a <Canvas> in your <UniformGrid>

Comment: The problem is that if I put a Canvas in my UniformGrid and draw the line there it wouldn't get to my Button1 control in the upper grid because that is out of boundaries...

Comment: This article gives interesting ideas, I'll try it out tomorrow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff646962.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Based on Charles Petzold ['Thinking outside the grid'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff646962.aspx) article I ended up with a structure like this:

```
<UserControl ... >
  <Grid ... >
    <local:SimpleUniformGrid ... >
      <Button ... />
      <Button ... />
      ...
    </local:SimpleUniformGrid>

    <Canvas>
      <Path ... /> 
      <Path ... />
      <Path ... />
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The key paragraph is this one:

"When processing the LayoutUpdated event, you don’t want to do anything that will cause another layout pass and get you embroiled in an infinite recursion. **That’s where the Canvas comes in handy: Because it always reports a zero size to its parent, you can alter elements in the Canvas without affecting layout**."

In addition to that I used Denis Vuyka MyThumb class from his [Dragable Objects article](http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/13/wpf-draggable-objects-and-simple-shape-connectors/)

The starting and ending points when creating lines can be determined using the GeneralTransform class as explained in [this article](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2007/07/wpf_finding_control_location.html):

```
    GeneralTransform transform = thumb.TransformToAncestor(this);
    Point rootPoint = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

The key lesson here was understanding that Canvas does not occupy any space inside of a Grid, so you can use it as a container for storing your Paths/LineGeometry and display them at any any coordinate in your view no matter if source/target controls belong to different containers.